# Filezilla public_html set permission from 00 to 750

Tags: upload, ftp, directory, filezilla

How do I set permission to public_html folder ?

Now it has permission 00 and when entering my site I get Forbidden error 403.

And when I'm trying to open public_html folder I get:

> 550 Can't change directory to public_html: Permission denied

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more information, like: what OS are you using; is this for local access ; etc.   (As a guess it sounds like you don't have sufficient administrative privileges to make the change)

Answer (score 2):

Use these commands:

```
(For ownership) sudo chown -R user:group folder/
(For permisions) sudo chmod -R 664 folder/
```

Check out the this wikipedia entry to learn more about chmod http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod